# Confusion with two predicates in one line inside a nested cond

Tags: scheme, racket, conditional-statements

I am having some trouble understanding the use of two predicates in a single line without an "and" or an "or" in Racket. Here is an example, with a comment where I'm confused:

```
(define (question x) 
 (cond
  [(cond
     [(even? x) (< 20 x)]  ; what is this doing? Are they both being evaluated at once?
     [else (even? x)])     
   (cond
     [(odd? x) ’day]
     [else ’night])]
   [else ’goodbye]))
```

I'm not sure what would happen if they both evaluated to true, or one to true and the other to false, etc. If anyone could shed some light on this silly question please do, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

`cond` clauses have the following form:

```
(<test> <result> ...)
```

In this case, the `<test>` is `(cond [(even? x) (< 20 x)] [else (even? x)])` and the `<result>` is `(cond [(odd? x) 'day] [else 'night])`.

The overall code, if I read it correctly, is the same as

```
(define (question x)
  (cond ((and (even? x) (< 20 x)) 'night)
        (else 'goodbye)))
```

Comment: Thanks! One more question -- I noticed the 'day part is not in your translation. Does this mean that [(odd x) 'day] is redundant and shouldn't be there in the original function?

Comment: @nnnm Trace through your code and see if there is _any_ situation where you'd return `'day`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(cond
  [(even? x) (< 20 x)]
  [else (even? x)])
```

In another language, such as ruby, this could be written as:

```
if x.even?
  x < 20
else
  x.even?
end
```